# Jersey - Get the HTTP response status in WADL

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, wadl

I am using Jersey 1.16 for exposing REST API 
I would like to have the HTTP response codes in the generated WADL 
I am documenting my code like in the  example below 
As far as I know the WADL spec (the XSD file) [supports the HTTP response codes](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/#x3-200002.10). 
As for now I cant get the HTTP response codes in the generated WADL.

- What is the right way to document / annotate the method in order to have the response code in the WADL?
- Is there any thing else that should be done in order to make Jersey adding the response code to the WADL?

**Code example:**

```
/**
 * Delete a workflow.
 * - 404 If the workflow does not exist.
 * - 202 Accepted with async status
 * - 204 No Content if remove is true (workflow is removed immediately)
 */
@DELETE
public Response deleteWorkflow (...) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: I believe you may find a way to extend the feature in [this article - or related "sub articles"](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/WADL)

Comment: As far as I understand this is the way the javadoc should look like (if one wants to expose response codes to WADL). I did not find yet what should be added / done in order to make jersey adding it to the WADL.

Answer (score 2):

First, to add information about the response codes, you can use a few Javadoc tags that are supported and used by Jersey when generating the WADL. You can find them here: [SupportedJavadocTagsForExtendedWADL](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/SupportedJavadocTagsForExtendedWADL)

Some custom tags exist; amongst them, some are related to specific response codes:

```
@response.representation.200.qname
@response.representation.200.mediaType
@response.representation.200.example
@response.representation.200.doc
```

Where you can replace `200` with any code.

So you could use the following javadoc on a method:

```
/**
 * A method used to demonstrate the supported custom tags.
 * 
 * @param code a code
 * 
 * @response.representation.200.mediaType application/xml
 * 
 */
@GET
@Path("info")
public Response info(@QueryParam("code") Integer code) {

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build(); 

}
```

Second (assuming you are using Maven), you need to configure the maven-javadoc-plugin to create a XML file that will contain this information: resource-doc.xml (with the ResourceDoclet provided by the wadl-resourcedoc-doclet artifact).

Plugin configuration (replace your.resource.package with your own resource package):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>javadoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <show>public</show>
        <subpackages>your.resource.package</subpackages>
        <doclet>com.sun.jersey.wadl.resourcedoc.ResourceDoclet</doclet>
        <docletPath>${path.separator}${project.build.outputDirectory}</docletPath>
        <docletArtifacts>
            <docletArtifact>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>wadl-resourcedoc-doclet</artifactId>
                <version>1.19</version>
            </docletArtifact>
            <docletArtifact>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.19</version>
            </docletArtifact>
            <docletArtifact>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </docletArtifact>
        </docletArtifacts>
        <!-- the following option is required as a work around for version > 2.5 of the javadoc 
            plugin which will be used by a maven version > 2.0.9 -->
        <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
        <additionalparam>-output ${project.build.outputDirectory}/resourcedoc.xml</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Third, extend `com.sun.jersey.api.wadl.config.WadlGeneratorConfig`:

```
public class CustomWadlGeneratorConfig extends WadlGeneratorConfig {

    @Override
    public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure() {
        return generator( WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.class ) 
            .prop( "resourceDocStream", "resourcedoc.xml" ) 
        .descriptions();
    }

}
```

Fourth and last, you need to instruct Jersey to use your CustomWadlGeneratorConfig. To do so, add it to your app's web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WadlGeneratorConfig</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.CustomWadlGeneratorConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The information from the javadoc tags should be included in your WADL.

Sadly, the existing extra tags do not allow a way to specify a specific `<doc>` per response code, which means that the same text (from the @return tag) will be added to every code:

```
<ns2:response status="200">
    <ns2:doc>
        <![CDATA[text from @return tag]]>
    </ns2:doc>
    <!- ... -->
</ns2:response>
<ns2:response status="404">
    <ns2:doc>
        <![CDATA[text from @return tag]]>
    </ns2:doc>
    <!- ... -->
</ns2:response>
```

But it should be feasible with a custom `com.sun.jersey.wadl.resourcedoc.DocProcessor` and `com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGenerator`, as shown in the [generate-wadl samples](http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo/com/sun/jersey/samples/generate-wadl/1.19/generate-wadl-1.19-project.zip).

Information and more examples:

- https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/HowToConfigureExtendedWADL
- http://biemond.blogspot.be/2013/08/custom-jersey-wadl-generation.html